# External email from specific database going to junk folder

Tags: email, database, spam

I have migrated from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2013, after which things are okay. I have four server plus two databases as below:

- Servers: CAS01, CAS02, MBX01, MBX02
- Database: DB1 mounted on MBX01 and DB2 mounted on MBX2

In addition we have Trend Micro Hosted Email Security v2.x. We have installed the agent on the two servers, and Symantec Messaging Getaway smart connector.

In Gmail, all external emails sent from DB2 users are going to junk folder, but DB1 users do not face this problem. In Hotmail all emails are going to junk for all users. I tried to create new Hotmail and Gmail accounts to test. When I compared message headers I noted this for the messages sent to Hotmail accounts:

```
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(28900001);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:5;SRVR:DB5PR07MB0853;H:BAY004-MC1F22.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery: abwl:0;wl:0;pcwl:0;kl:0;iwl:0;ijl:0;dwl:0;dkl:0;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:J;WIMS-SenderIP:MYIP;WIMS-SPF:MYDomain%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:MYDomain%2ec;WIMS-822:newmb2%40MYDomain%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:newmb2%40MYDomain%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102420017);RF:JunkEmail;OFR:SpamFilterAuthJ;
```

In addition, I would like to share the following with you:

1. Q: Did the mail flow work fine before installing the agent?
   A: I did not check, so I'm not source.
2. Q: Does the issue happen if the users in DB2 send emails by using OWA?
   A: Not been done for Gmail working fine and Hotmail going to junk folder.
3. Q: What happens when you create a new Mailbox in DB2 and test?
   A: The same. Nothing has changed.
4. Q: Check if the issue persists when moving a user from DB2 to DB1?
   A: I have created a new mailbox in DB2 and moved it to DB1, and the same thing happends.
5. Q: Temporarily disable the agent to test?
   A: I have disabled it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Security.SE! What is your actual question here? Also, could you explain how this relates to information security?

Comment: I think this should be migrated to [SF]. The question doesn't seem to be about information security, but it does show research effort.